# GWT - JNDI - DB connection error

Tags: java, gwt, jndi

I am converting my working application to use JNDI to resolve timeouts when deployed to the server. When I test locally I get the following error (I have ensured that I am using the local path in the context.xml when running this test):

```
Context Created
Error connecting to database - not good eh
javax.naming.NoInitialContextException: Need to specify class name in environment or system property, or as an applet parameter, or in an application resource file:  java.naming.factory.initial
at javax.naming.spi.NamingManager.getInitialContext(Unknown Source)

Starting Jetty on port 8888
[WARN] Exception while dispatching incoming RPC call
com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.UnexpectedException: Service method 'public abstract org.AwardTracker.client.Account org.AwardTracker.client.DBConnection.authenticateAccount(java.lang.String,java.lang.String)' threw an unexpected exception: java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RPC.encodeResponseForFailure(RPC.java:389)
```

The code is:

```
public class MySQLConnection extends RemoteServiceServlet implements DBConnection {
//TODO
//  •Manage the connection in single class for whole application.
//  •Initialise the data source at application start up single time.
//  •Don't handle any exception in service implementation just throw it to client or if handled then re-throw some meaning full exception back to client.
//  •Add throws in all the methods for all the RemoteService interfaces whenever needed.

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

// Get DataSource from JNDI (defined in context.xml file)   
Context ctx = null;
DataSource ds = null;

public MySQLConnection() {

     try {
        // Get DataSource from JNDI (defined in context.xml file)
         ctx = new InitialContext();
         ds = (DataSource)ctx.lookup("java:comp/env/jdbc/mydatabase");
         Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
         } catch (Exception e) {
             //NEVER catch exceptions like this
             System.out.println("Error connecting to database - not good eh");
             e.printStackTrace();
         }
}
```

And my context.xml is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Context>
    <Resource name="jdbc/mydatabase" 
              auth="Container"
              type="javax.sql.DataSource" 
              username="glyndwr" 
              password="***********"
              driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
              url="jdbc:mysql://localhost/glyndwr?autoReconnect=true"
              validationQuery="select 1"
              removeAbandoned="true"
              removeAbandonedTimeout="120"
              logAbandoned="true"
              maxWait="60"
              maxActive="10" 
              maxIdle="4"/>
    <!-- url="jdbc:mysql://localhost/glyndwr?autoReconnect=true"; -->
    <!-- url="jdbc:mysql://mysql5.metawerx.net:3506/glyndwr?autoReconnect=true" -->
</Context>
```

And my web.xml is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<!DOCTYPE web-app
    PUBLIC "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.3//EN"
    "http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd">

<web-app>

    <context-param>
        <!-- max size of the upload request -->
        <param-name>maxSize</param-name>
        <param-value>3145728</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <context-param>
        <!-- Useful in development mode to slow down the uploads in fast networks.
         Put the number of milliseconds to sleep in each block received in the server.
         false or 0, means don't use slow uploads  -->
        <param-name>slowUploads</param-name>
        <param-value>0</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <!-- ServeletContext Implementation for memory leaks -->

    <listener>
        <listener-class>
            org.AwardTracker.server.ServletContextImpl
        </listener-class>
    </listener>

    <servlet>
         <servlet-name>mySQLConnection</servlet-name>
         <servlet-class>org.AwardTracker.server.MySQLConnection</servlet-class>
    </servlet>

    <!-- servlet>
        <servlet-name>uploadServlet</servlet-name>
        <!- This is the default servlet, it puts files in session -
        <servlet-class>gwtupload.server.UploadServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet -->

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>uploadServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.AwardTracker.server.MyCustomisedUploadServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping> 
        <servlet-name>mySQLConnection</servlet-name> 
        <url-pattern>/org.AwardTracker.AwardTracker/MySQLConnection</url-pattern> 
    </servlet-mapping>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>uploadServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.gupld</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <!-- Default page to serve -->
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>AwardTracker.html</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>    

</web-app>
```

Your help would be greatly appreciated.

Regards,

Glyn

Comment: @user3218114 Hi Braj, as you can see above I have finally got around to implementing JNDI. Any chance you could have a look at this issue please? Regards, Glyn.

Answer (score 0):

`context.xml` is a Tomcat-specific file, and you're using Jetty (I suppose you're using GWT DevMode), which is configured differently.

That said, JNDI in DevMode might work but is not officially supported. You should rather use an external server tailored to your need (and probably closer to your production environment)

Comment: Hi Thomas (@http://stackoverflow.com/users/116472/thomas-broyer), Yes I am using GWT DevMode. Having to upload this to Host's servers in order to test each change is extremely time consuming and inconvenient. Is there another way that will enable me to test this locally (i.e., on my laptop)? I must explain that I am not technical and am developing this for my Cub Scout Pack. Thank you for your help, Glyn.

Comment: Installing a local Tomcat instance is almost as easy as downloading, unpacking and launching. You can even have your IDE auto-deploy your app there. ⇒ https://tomcat.apache.org

Comment: Hi Thomas (@stackoverflow.com/users/116472/thomas-broyer), I did not know that is what you meant. I do already have a local Tomcat instance. This was all working allowing me to do local testing until I changed to JNDI. I have uploaded the war to my Host's servers and it seems to be connecting to their DB. I just have an issue with an incorrect SQL that I have rectified and am waiting for the new war to be implemented. Therefore, the code is correct so I surmise that there is some setup that I have not done correctly. Regards, Glyn

Comment: I added "System.out.println("DataSource ds = " + ds);" which returns "DataSource ds = null". So the issue seam to be with:

ctx = new InitialContext();

 ds = (DataSource)ctx.lookup("java:comp/env/jdbc/mydatabase"); Regards, Glyn

Comment: Is this when you deploy to your local Tomcat? or still in DevMode? In DevMode, this is expected. If it's in your local Tomcat, then you might want to ask another question, or update your question ([edit]) and re-tag it for [tag:tomcat], as this would be unrelated to GWT.

Comment: Hi Thomas (@stackoverflow.com/users/116472/thomas-broyer), I am not sure what you mean. I am using Eclipse Kepler where I start the server, run the application, copy the url into Explorer and then use / test the application. I have had someone else helping me as well and they have check my web.xml and context.xml which they say is fine. They then advised me to copy the <Context> to </Context> into my Server.xml. However, now the server will not start. No error messages, just does not start! Regards, Glyn

Comment: If by "start the server" you mean Tomcat, then this is independent from GWT. If you mean "run as... Web application", then you're using GWT's DevMode, where the context.XML is ignored, as it's not a Tomcat server.

Comment: Hi Thomas (@stackoverflow.com/users/116472/thomas-broyer), First, within Eclipse, I start the server (in the server tab I click on the green arrow and eventually the messages "Server stopped" changes to "Server started". I then select the project and go the the Eclipse menu where I select run as Web Application and eventually an url is displayed which I copy into Internet Explorer to run the application. The other person helping me tells me that I need to find the full log (as against the error messages displayed in Eclipse). You wouldn't happen to know where that is would you? Regards, Glyn.

Comment: So you're starting a Tomcat instance (I'm assuming it's Tomcat) and then you're starting GWT's DevMode. If you haven't unchecked the "embedded server" in the launch configuration for the GWT "Web Application" and changed the `startupUrl` to point to your Tomcat, then you're basically never using Tomcat and it's useless starting it; and you're then trying to have your webapp deployed into the Jetty server embedded in GWT DevMode, which won't do JNDI. See also http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideCompilingAndDebugging.html#How_do_I_use_my_own_server_in_development_mode_instead_of_GWT%27s

Comment: Hi Thomas (@stackoverflow.com/users/116472/thomas-broyer), I have read the document and am not sure on how to do step 2. I have also found another document that said to use, from the menu bar, Run/ Run As/ Run on Server. However, when I do this I get an error "HTTP Status 404 - /AwardTRacker_N/", "type Status report", "message /AwardTracker_N/", "description The requested resource is not available.". Regards, Glyn